# Failing to create folder in /Var/www/html from file.php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have a AWS EC2 server with phpMyAdmin to manage it.

Everything is working correctly but I would like to be able to create another folder in the /var/www/html directory to add files..

This is my code but it just keeps returning the error to me! any ideas??

```
// STEP 2.2 Create a folder in server to store posts'pictures
   $folder = "/var/www/html/bloggerFiles/Posts/" . $id;


if(!file_exists($folder)){
    if (!mkdir($folder, 0777, true)) {//0777
        die('Failed to create folders...');
    }

}
```

I would normally create that folder in the terminal by using sudo mkdir, but when I add sudo Nothing works!

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the folder(s) you are accessing are set to `read and write` folder permissions, then use this function:

```
function newFolder($path, $perms)
    $path = str_replace(' ', '-', $path);
    $oldumask = umask(0); 
    mkdir($path, $perms); // or even 01777 so you get the sticky bit set  (0777)
    umask($oldumask);
    return true;
}
```

This fixed it for me.

You can create new folder doing this: `newFolder('PathToFolder/here', 0777);`

**EDIT**: Please have a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mx2XOFBp8M
**EDIT**: Also have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#1207

**EDIT**: Storing functions in classes and safely use the function

```
class name_here
{
    public function newFolder($path, $perms, $deny_if_folder_exists){
        $path = 'PATH_TO_POSTS/'.$path; // This is for setting the root to PATH TO POSTS
        $path = str_replace('../', '', $path); // Deny the path to go out of var/www/html/PATH_TO_POSTS/$path
        if( $deny_if_folder_exists === true ){
            if(file_exists($path)){return false;}
            $old_umask = umask(0);
            mkdir($path, $perms);
            umask($old_umask);

        }elseif( $deny_if_folder_exists === false ){
            $old_umask = umask(0);
            mkdir($path, $perms);
            umask($old_umask);
        }else{
            return false; // Unknown
        }
    }
}
/* Call the function by doing this: */
$manage = new name_here;
$manage->newFolder('test', 777, true); // Test will appear in /var/www/html/PATH_TO_POSTS/$path, but if the folder exists it will return false and not create the folder.
```

**EDIT**: If this file is called from html it will re create the path, so I will it has to be called from /html/

**EDIT**: How to use the name_here class

```
/*
 How to call the function?
  $manage = new name_here; Creates a variable to an object (The class)
  $manage->newFolder('FolderName', 0777, true); // Will create a folder to the path,
  but this fill needs to be called from the html the root directory is set to the
  "PATH_TO_POSTS/" basicly means you cannot do this function from "html/somewhere/form.php",
  UNLESS the "PATH_TO_POSTS" is in the same directory as form.php
*/
```

Comment: edited: `newFolder('PathToFolder/here', 077);` to `newFolder('PathToFolder/here', 0777);`

Comment: Hi thanks for that! Not sure if the folder I am accessing is read and write. How would I check that?

Comment: @Jack Are you using a local host or are you running an online server? Is the server hosted from a company or home hosted, also which operative system are you using? This information is needed to explain how you will fix  your problem..

Comment: it is on AWS, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jack, example: I am hosting my `Local` server on my `macbook` which is running `MacOS` (Operative system), I had the same problem on my mac

Comment: @Jack it sounds like you need to take a step back and read up on basic Linux file permissions. You're going to have trouble administering your servers until you understand this basic Linux concept. People are giving you the correct answer here but you don't understand enough yet to comprehend the answers you are given. Maybe start here: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: So are you the one hosting the server or is it hosted from a company

Comment: @Jack If the server is hosted from a company please contact your seller and tell him to manage the permissions for your need

Comment: Oh ok, It is hosted on my local macBook. Same as you

Comment: My Posts folder is read and write for the owners permissions and then just READ for group&public permissions

Comment: do the same with www and html

Comment: Thanks for the links, But I think I have to edit the permissions through the terminal after I have connected to my EC2 DB

Comment: I managed to change the Posts folder to read and write. Which let me add the file with my previous code... but isn't setting it to 777 (read and write for everyone) risky?

Comment: @Jack, depends on how you use it, if you would add it to a class and make the function private and then call the function from another function only on places you want to create new folder / files

Comment: @Jack, please take a look at the last EDIT

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg Hi just checked that out, My server is for an IOS app. Anyway if I make just the one file "Posts" public everything works correctly, but i'm not sure if that is good for security reasons. Your latest edit, If I place that in my PHP file how would it work?

Comment: The folder I am creating is not public, but the folder that the other folder is placed in is public.

Comment: @Jack, is it possible to get in a "Talk" session, such as a stack overflow chat, it looks pretty nasty having a long comment section :), Just start one if you want, I am also avaible at skype

Comment: Yeh absolutely!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124723/discussion-between-jack-and-richard-olsen-sandberg).